# Made a grammar edit to "maths" and it got rejected?

Tags: discussion, editing, suggested-edits

I made an edit to a question where in addition to correction "maths" to "math", I also added math formatting. It was apparently rejected--the reviewer made the same math formatting edits that I made, but rejected the correction from "maths" to "math". Is "maths" actually correct in some instances?

Comment: Second Google result for `maths math`: http://grammarist.com/spelling/math-maths/.

Comment: I suppose you are talking about this [suggested edit](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/74437). It was not rejected, by improved (edited). They are not the same thing, although I do not know the subtleties. IIRC if you see that your suggested edit was rejected by Community♦ user, you do not have much to worry about.

Comment: Apropos threads: [(1)](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3), [(2)](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1503).

Comment: "your suggested edit was rejected by Community♦ user" - that apparently means the ""suggested edit was helpful" checkbox was unchecked.

Comment: Before someone else links to it: [english.SE question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/990).

Comment: +1 This is a perfectly valid question for someone who has never seen the term "maths" before.  It took some "getting used to" for me.

Comment: I always want to change it the other way - it grates, but getting used to it makes life so much easier ...

Comment: @MarkBennet I agree that it grates, but I still cannot get used to people saying "math" rather than maths. It just feels wrong. Kinda...truncated, like they stopped mid word, as if they were interrupted...

Comment: @user1729 How did you get that number!! Just mentally add the 's' ...

Comment: @MartinSleziak Yes, "if you see that your suggested edit was rejected by Community♦ user, you do not have much to worry about" is correct. This is a [very recent change](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/182983/224469): rejections by Community (which can be either edit conflicts or rewritten edits) no longer count toward the automatic edit ban.

Comment: @MarkBennet This is just my pseudonym. My real name is user10513. But don't tell anyone.

Comment: FWIW, spelling is not grammar.

Comment: @PeterTaylor are you sure pluralizing a singular noun isn't a *grammars* issue?

Comment: @ZettaSuro The way I think about "maths" is we start with mathematics and contract it to "math's". However, this looks silly. So we get "maths". Note that if you want to argue that "math" is correct then I do not know how you can do this without actually arguing that "math'" (with an apostrophy) is correct instead...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just so this doesn't fall under "unanswered." `:)`

As can be seen in this [English.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/990/which-is-correct-math-or-maths) question (linked by Ｊ. M. in the comments), "maths" is the British English form of the American English "math."  As this is an international site, either is acceptable.

Comment: A further indication of its acceptability: if you type in the url `maths.stackexchange.com` and `mathematics.stackexchange.com`, they both get redirected to our main site. (Full disclaimer, I was the one who asked SE to do the forwarding.)